# Building multimodule maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

Hi I've searched the net, read a bunch of articles, so questions and documentation but I can not find solution, here is my problem.

I have a multimodule maven project which contains three modules A,B and C. 
A and B independent and C is depend on A and B, and of course I have a parent project. I also have a jenkins server set up to build these projects, and a nexus repository.

My problem is that when I build the project the maven builds A and B correctly but for C it downloads an older artifact from the nexus repository and of course it fails to build module C. 
How can I make the maven to use the currently built jars which installed into the local repository instead of the older ones on nexus?

Version of A and B and C set to 1.1.{build_number}-SNAPSHOT with maven version plugin, and as I understand maven should use the newer from local but it does not do it. 
Initially I do not want to post hundreds of lines of pom.xmls but if you need section I will provide it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: I'm using Jenkins and Artifactory, and when I build a multimodule project, Maven first has a look to the local Maven repo (.m2/repository). Next, when the build is OK, the binaries (A, B and C) are uploaded into Artifactory. Maybe you have an option with Jenkins/Nexus to use the local repo instead of the remote repo?

Comment: Hi Bruno thanks for your answer. I want exactly what you are doing, but somehow maven in my case ignores the local repository and I can not figure it out how to make it use the currently built artifacts. Any idea where should I look?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180696/maven-not-using-local-repository

Comment: Maven refreshs the local dependency one time per day, so maybe you just have to change this setting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148111/maven-snapshot-updates

Comment: Hi it was set to always but I set tot never right now to prevent downloading of snpashot artifacts but still the newer artifact in my local repo is being ignored.

Comment: If you build on your machine, you confirm that the build result is OK?

Comment: The best test for a multi module project is to clean the local repository and just run `mvn clean package` if something goes wrong your build is not configured well. That's what i would check first.

Comment: Totally agree with @khmarbaise .. most likely your multi module projects has an incorrect setup that prevents the Maven reactor from resolving A and B from C within the project correctly.

Comment: You should post your own solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been setting the version numbers in the submodule's poms and changed to inherit version number from parent pom. In module `C`'s pom module `A` and `B` versions set to `${project.version}`