# Maven release plugin - how to publish only a snapshot?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm using maven release plugin to deploy new versions of software.
When running

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

Everything works as expected.
If I tell maven to release version 2.1, it publishes an artifact `2.1` as well as a `2.2-20210205.061032-1`, which I guess is some kind of snapshot. I'm wondering if it´s possible to perform a release for a new snapshot version ONLY?

The use case being that I have made some changes I want to publish for testing, before commiting to a final release. Something like `2.2-SNAPSHOT`, or something like `2.2-YYYYMMDD.HHmmSS-X`.
When prompted by maven to enter the next version, if I enter `2.2-SNAPSHOT`, it just repeats the question again.

Please advice on how to achieve this, or if I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to deploy a SNAPSHOT, just run

`mvn clean deploy`

The Maven Release Plugin is meant for release versions.

Comment: Oh, it was that simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`SNAPSHOT`s are meant to be very fluid, to the level of a dependent project "immediately" picking up changes to the `SNAPSHOT` dependency, whatever "immediately" means: it could be directly in an IDE, or while doing rapid builds on a command line but also on a CI server. I agree with the answer of *J Fabian Meier* that you can deploy a `SNAPSHOT` using `mvn deploy`.

However, if you are delivering a pre-release version for testing to a different team, you probably want them to have something that is more stable than a `SNAPSHOT`. When testing it is often important that you can reason about what version (or constellation of versions) you are running, and this is not quite the case with `SNAPSHOT`s (you may push up a new version then by quasi-accident, users may or may not [force-update their `SNAPSHOT`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9697970/1325216), or [Maven may not look for new `SNAPSHOT`s until tomorrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2148178/1325216)).

You may be better off with versions that are released (from Maven's perspective) using the Maven Release Plugin (and benefit from [the safeguards it offers](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html)), but just using version "numbers" that indicate it is a pre-release: 2.2-rc, 2.2-beta (I'm sure [SemVer has ideas](https://semver.org/) of the exact pattern to use, and [so does Maven](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#version-order-specification)).